# In React, how to pass "this.state" as parameter to "socket.on" callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am using Socket.io and React, and I have a function:

```
    this.state.socket.on("newMentions", function (data) {
      this.setState({         // Cannot read "this" here.
        newMentions: data
      })
    })
```

The `socket` is store in `state` of this class component, and I want to define its `on` event, which should set some new date to the state by using `this.setState`.

But the `this.setState` is inaccessible, I think I need to pass it as a paramete to the `socket.on` function. But how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ES6 arrow function in order to access lexical context

```
 this.state.socket.on("newMentions",(data)=> {
      this.setState({        
        newMentions: data
      })
    })
```